# Проблема с кодировкой UTF-8 сервер Tomcat ubuntu

Tags: java, веб-программирование, servlet, tomcat, utf-8

В браузере строка отображается как-то так: Р›РµРѕРЅРёРґ.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Декодер показывает что она приходит в Windows-1251 хотя вроде как в сервлете прописано все как в примерах.

код из сервлета:

```
req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

код из server.xml:

```
 <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
           useBodyEncodingForURI="true"/>
```

Все файлы в UTF-8 закодированы.
Не догоняю как исправить эту проблему уже день, заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Добавил к коду в сервлете вот это: resp.setContentType("text/json; charset=windows-1251"); и получил корректный ответ, но хотелось бы разобраться где я ошибся и почему не работает UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что браузер отображает вашу строку в неверном представлении - изначально вы не дали ему никакой информации об исходном представлении строки. Поэтому ему пришлось импровизировать "на лету", что вылилось в кракозябры на экране.

Добавив параметр в хидер ContentType вы это сделали - указали явную инструкцию как обработать вашу строку на экране.

Есть ещё один путь:

в теле страницы указать тег meta с атрибутом charset: `<meta charset="UTF-8" />`